# Day Name For Date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table with multiple columns.  Two of those column are as follows:

Column Name   Type
-----------   -----
Use_Date      Date
Day_Name      Char

There are 5 rows in the table each has a different date value in Use_Date and Day_Name is blank.  I want to update the table and set the day with the name of the day for each row's date.

Something like...

```
update mytable
set Day_Name = date("D", strtotime('Use_Date'));
```

The above however, does not work!

Comment: You should add a tag indicating which database you use, just in case it makes a difference. It will also bring more attention to your question.

Comment: You are apparently placing a PHP `date()` function directly into a SQL string. That won't work. MySQL [has native functions for date handling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) which can be used, or you need to correctly concatenate the result of the PHP date function into the SQL string.

Comment: In particular, [there is `DAYNAME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) with which you could `UPDATE mytable SET Day_Name = DAYNAME(Use_Date)`.  But you could also just retrieve that value at query time using that function, rather than storing it in the first place, as in `SELECT DAYNAME(Use_Date) AS Day_Name FROM mytable`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`DAYNAME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function for this purpose. Something like

```
update mytable
set Day_Name = DAYNAME(Use_Date);
```